# How to suppress the ŝcreensaver right way

Tags: winapi, mfc

I must suppress (not disable) the window screensaver while a long machine-process is runnning.

Is simulate a little mouse movement with SendInput(..) the right way?

Comment: @Remy: You are right. My mother tongue is not anglais so I did found this.  Supress - prevent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, it is not.**

On XP and later, use [`SetThreadExecutionState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208.aspx) instead:

> Enables an application to inform the system that it is in use, **thereby preventing the system from entering sleep or turning off the display** while the application is running.
>
> ...
>
> Multimedia applications, such as video players and presentation applications, must use `ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED` when they display video **for long periods of time without user input**.

Despite what the documentation says ("*This function does not stop the screen saver from executing*"), this DOES stop the screensaver.

On earlier versions of Windows, you can handle the [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360.aspx) message instead.  When the `wParam` is set to `SC_SCREENSAVE`, if you don't pass the message to `DefWindowProc()`, the screensaver will not be run, **unless** the screensaver is password protected, in which case it is run regardless of what happens to the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message:

> If password protection is enabled by policy, the screen saver is started regardless of what an application does with the `SC_SCREENSAVE` notification— even if fails to pass it to `DefWindowProc`.

Another option is to use [`SystemParametersInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx) to set `SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE` to `TRUE` so Windows thinks a screensaver is already running so it won't start the default screensaver.

Comment: Thx! This is much clearer and more comprehensive explained than the link you mentioned,